# How can i make in the blend tree that the player will keep walking if he is also aiming with the weapon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now when the player is aiming he can't walk. I need to make it stop aiming to be able to keep walking. I'm using the mouse right button for aiming with aiming parameter false/true.

And i created a blend tree there i mixed between Walk and Idle.
But now i want also to mix between Walk and Aiming.

[image: Controller]

And when i make double click on Movement there the blend tree:

[image: Controller001]

So now i can walk and when i stop walking with the keys it's idling.
I can also use the mouse right button for aiming one click on the mouse right button will keep aiming another click will stop aiming.

But when i'm in the aiming state i can't walk.

The question is how do i mix the Walk with the Aiming (The aiming animation i have is called: Rifle_Aiming_Idle there is also animation called Rifle_Aiming_Walk_F) ?

This animations are not my own. But i wonder if i should mix the aiming_Idle with the Walk(HumanoidWalk i have already in the blend tree or to use somehow only with the Rifle_Aiming_Walk_F somehow).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Soldier : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var inputVelx = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var inputVely = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        transform.Rotate(0, inputVelx, 0);

        anim.SetFloat("VelX", inputVelx);
        anim.SetFloat("VelY", inputVely);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            anim.SetBool("Aiming", !anim.GetBool("Aiming"));
        }
    }
}
```

There is a short video clip in youtube the owner of this package he made showing the movements too of the aiming/s. I'm not sure just how to make that the character will walk and aiming at the same time:

[Sci Fi Space Soldier - PolygonR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QX-CDGm6dJQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create multiple **Layers** in the animator controller.
Then add **Avatar mask**. Please take a look at here:
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/how-to-animate-specific-body-parts-using-avatar-mask-in-unity

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can duplicate your shoot animation and rename it as shoot_walking then animate it.

Also check it:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState.AddMixingTransform.html